# Solar powered 5W DC12V pump

Tags: hobbyist

I'm trying to power a little pump ([http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00JWJIC0K](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JWJIC0K)) with a solar panel I have.

I've stepped the voltage out of the panel down to 12V with a buck converter. The panel is currently outputting 4A which should be plenty but the pump won't come on. I did buy a 2nd pump in case the first one was bad but no dice. From my limited understanding, as long as the voltage matches the pump the output from the panel shouldn't matter as long as it's high enough.

Would too much wattage prevent the pump from starting?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to be within the voltage range and supply the current (remember that a motor will need a large gulp of current to start it). What is the voltage of the PV panel? What is the voltage of the motor? What is the power of the PV panel? What is the power of the motor? What is the power output of the PV panel in situation you have placed it in? EDIT: PS, have you checked the pump works by using a battery?

Comment: PV Panel Output: 20-30V which I step down to 12V.  Motor voltage is 12V.  PV Panel power is: 4A (so ~36W, I believe).  Motor is 5W.  Thanks Andy!

Comment: Good point re: checking with battery.  I haven't done that yet

Answer (score 1):

A dc to dc converter is going to be a low impedance load on your panel. Check the panel voltage when you connect the DC to DC converter with a load on it and see if it is dropping too low.

A solar panel cannot supply infinite ammounts of current. When you draw too much current the voltage falls and falls fast. You may need a [maximum peak power tracking circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_point_tracking) to regulate the voltage. An MPPT will also usually have an indicator to let you know if it can provide the current to the load.

A DC to DC converter is not going to find the optimum point of voltage and current for efficient power draw.

Lastly, the panel needs to have enough power from the sun. A good minimum figure to use is 300W/m^2 (thats watts per meter squared, at the equator it is 1000W/m^2). You also need to factor panel efficiency and your panel may have some info printed on a label on the back and the testing conditions or in a datasheet. Anyway you need to find the amount of power that your panel is receiving, so calculate the area then multiply it by 300W/m^2. This will give you a minimum ballpark number of how much energy the panel is receiving. The panel can't collect all of that energy, some of it is heat and the panel is not 100% efficient. So you need to take the total energy received and multiply it by the efficiency of the panel (which will probably be around 10 to 15%). I'll recap

300W/m^2*(area of the panel)*(the efficiency of the panel) = power received

That number better be higher than 5W, or your pump wont start. You'd also better try this on a sunny day pointing the panel's face normal to the direction of the sun (perpendicular). You will also lose some power to the inefficiency with any converter you use, but that will be in the DC converters datasheet and it varies with voltage.